# Firefox blocking access to Content-Length Response Header

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, fetch, content-length

I have a simple fetch call to an audio file on S3, and am using the `Content-Length` header to generate a loading progress bar. On Chrome and Safari, this is totally functional, but Firefox is returning `null` for `res.headers.get('Content-Length').

```
const res = await fetch(src)
const length = res.headers.get('Content-Length') // null on Firefox
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues? My suspicion was the browser restricting CORS access, but I have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: In my case, I was making a HEAD request to retrieve the object size and got the same issue. I solved it by adding `<ExposeHeader>Content-Length</ExposeHeader>` to my bucket CORS configuration

Comment: @Andres Thank you very match! Your tip helped. Maybe make a proper answer?